# Nodejs module exports

Tags: node.js

In my node app, I'm defining models (using Sequelize ORM) in two different files: models/app-acl.js and models/app-models.js;

then I'm importing them in a third file (models.js) where I'm defining the relationships between models:

```
//file models.js
var aclModel = require('./app-acl.js');
var appModel = require('./app-models.js');

//defining relationships...
aclModel.Group.hasMany(aclModel.User, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
...


//exporting models:
module.exports = {
    aclModel: aclModel,
    appModel: appModel
}
```

Doing this, in other parts of the app I can do

```
var models = require('models/models.js')
```

and access all models by models.aclModel... and models.appModel

The thing is that sometimes I need to do operation on arbitrary model, such as a "find" without knowing if it is a aclModel or a appModel; so I would like to export both under the same name; something like:

```
module.exports = {
    models: aclModel + appModel //merged together
}
```

by this I would be able to do

```
models[name].find.....
```

being "name" a model from aclModel or from appModel, and it will work in both cases;

I thought to merge together aclModel and appModel in model.js before exporting like this:

```
function merge (destination, source) {
    for (var property in source)
        destination[property] = source[property];
    return destination;
}

module.exports = {
    models: merge(aclModel, appModel)
}
```

but this doesn't work; does anybody have a solution for doing this?

Comment: "this doesn't work" can you be a little clearer on that point? what output are you expecting, and what are you actually getting?

Comment: Well I can only say that doing this, model[name].find says cannot find of undefined... Before, aclModel[name].find was working (if name was a model from aclModl); probably there's something wrong in the way I use to merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after clarifying your question in the comments (next time save everyone's time by including a real program that expresses your question not just snippets and ellipses), my first thought is your design is probably ultimately misguided but nonetheless is achievable and straightforward in javascript.

Put your files in this structure:

```
models/index.js
models/acl-model.js
models/app-model.js
```

In your `models/index.js` do this:

`var _ = require('lodash');
_.extend(module.exports, require('./acl-model'), require('./app-model'));`

This will combine all the properties of your two model modules into the index module. In case of a name duplication conflict, the last one will win.

Then you can get a reference to the index with `require('models');` or a specific one with `require('models/acl-model');`. The `index.js` one will support `models[name]` dynamic property lookup access. Thus you can do:

`var models = require('models');
var name = "Group";
models[name].find();`

As long as one of your model modules has a model called "Group", that will work.

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing before, but in that way models[name] doesn't work; you need to call models.aclModel[name] or models.appModel[name]... But if you don't know if "name" is a aclModel or a appModel, you can't use it ...

Comment: This works just fine. `models[name].find()` will work correctly if `name` is a string with value "aclModel" or "appModel". You understand that javascript object property names must be strings and only strings, right? You can never do `someObject[someVariableThatIsNotAString]` in javascript.

Comment: If `name` is actually an object, just basic variables and dynamic typing will work fine: `name.find()` is all you need.

Comment: Ok probably I'm not explaining well: what I need to do is models[name].find(...) where find is Sequelize's query function to retrieve the model's data; and name is for example "Group" that is a model defined in aclModel; (but could be for example the name of a model defined in appModel); I would like to have a way to call Sequelize's find() method on any model without knowing if it is a model from appModel or from aclModel

Comment: Updated based on your comments.

Comment: I'll keep in mind your suggestions to write better and understandable questions

Comment: Just want to add that reading the docs, it seems that extend() is deprecated and now assign() should be used

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use :

```
module.exports = {
    ...aclModel,
    ...appModel
}
```

it is a sample method